# mySQL commands not recognized in the Unix Shell

Tags: mysql, macos, unix

I just installed mySQL (mysql-5.5.19-osx10.6-x86_64) on my Mac OS X and when I try to run one of the mysql command like `mysqld` I get the following error:

```
-bash: mysqld: command not found
```

Is there something I am missing?  I've tried restarting Terminal and I made sure to run the command for the files located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

Thanks

Comment: do you actually have a `mysqld` file? What happens when you try running with the full path name, for example `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` (*if* that's where it is)?

Comment: I do actually have the file but when I go to the directory and run `mysqld` I get the bash error.  But just right now I ran `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` and the command was recognized.  Why couldn't I just run `mysqld`?

Comment: @EverTheLearner: Because it's not in the [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8612248/166339).

Comment: yah, in that case see @Asaph's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/local/mysql/bin` is most likely not in your system's [PATH environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). You can add it to your path by adding a line like this to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

(you'll need to restart your shell for the above to take effect.) Another option is to symlink the MySQL binaries to a directory that is already on your path. Something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld /usr/bin/mysqld
```

You'll need to enter the root password in order to add symlinks to `/usr/bin`. Alternatively, you could make no changes at all and simply use a fully qualified path to execute the command

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
```